# Store Javascript function result into variable

Tags: javascript, function

I am doing the following:

```
elemDrop: function(elem) {
    return elem;
},

elemAddRel: function(json) {

    var elem = this.elemDrop;

    console.log(elem);

    $(elem.item[0]).addClass('showTab').attr('rel', json.pageId);

},
```

However when i console.log 'elem', it just stores the entire function into a variable. How can i actually store the result of the function into the variable?

Comment: didn't you mean `this.elemDrop`?

Comment: Please post the entire object code that these two functions are part of. `this.chuckDrop` could be initialized somewhere else in the said object.

Comment: I think your code snippet is wrong. Is `this.chunkDrop` a reference to `this.elemDrop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
var elem = this.chunkDrop();
```

The use of the brackets `()` will trigger the function and return the result rather than setting the variable equal to the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to execute the function by `this.chunkDrop();`